# Customizable DataSet in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I faced interesting probled: in my report I have local DataSet which wraps stored procedure. This SP have couple of input parameters (for filtering purposes and this functionality cannot be moved to report) which defaulted to `NULL` (i.e. no params passed). Now I want to add chart which should pass parameter to this SP to display only filtered data.

Question: how could I pass param to Dataset's SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found correct solution. I moved repeatable part of report to stand-alone report and embed it as Subreport into main one. Due this action I've added required DataSet parameter as input parameter of subreport and pass it from main report. This solution working fine as displaying report in ReportControl as exporting to Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: You're still passing a parameter to a sub-report.

Comment: So what? It is one parameter, which contains single string which using in filtering query.

Comment: Why didn't you say so... now that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference parameters from the Data Set in other Data Sets while accommodating a null value as a default parameter. Name the parameters differently and set the value of the Chart's parameter to the other dataset's parameter.

Comment: It is not the case. I have about 10 repeatable charts. Do you suggest to create 10 input parameters? That is funny.

Comment: You can reference the same source parameter across all of them, IF the parameter is the same for all charts. Still you'll need to have parameters in your chart's dataset.